# Nested annotation in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-aggregation

I have three models

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=100)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    modela = ForeignKey(ModelA)

class ModelC(models.Model):
    modelb = ForeignKey(ModelB)
```

How can I print all ModelA objects with the number of 'associated' ModelC objects?

Output:

```
name, num model c objects
======
Some name, 17
Another name, 3
```

I've tried making a queryset from ModelA like this:

```
ModelA.objects.all().values('name').annotate('modelb_set__modela_set')
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Count` here and reference ModelC in your query

```
from django.db.models import Count
ModelA.objects.all().values('name').annotate(num_model_c_objects=Count('modelb__modelc'))
```